# Error passing W3.org Validator: Illegal character in scheme data

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am trying to pass a file path with `src` (`<video src="C:\Users\exampleuser\example.mp4"></video>`) through W3C's validator.  However, I am given the error:

> Bad value `C:\Users\exampleuser\example.mp4` for attribute `src` on element `video`: Illegal character in scheme data: `\` is not allowed.

Why is the backslash from a file path disallowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A video element src attribute expects an URL, not a windows filepath. The URL version of that path would be `file:///c:/Users/exampleuser/example.mp4`

As it is, the string `C:\Users\exampleuser\example.mp4` is attempted to be parsed as a URL with a URL scheme `C:`, and a backslash is not a [valid character after a scheme declaration](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#cannot-be-a-base-url-path-state).

Answer (score -1):

You have an error on your video tag, you forgot closing >, use this :

```
<video src="C:/Users/exampleuser/example.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  Yes, the question had a typo, but it is asking about an error unrelated to that typo.  Even if the question could be solved by fixing a typo, answering typo questions is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I actually had that in the original code but forgot it here.  Edited.

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica validators are not that smart, wrong tag declarations are more than a valid response for this case

Comment: @Lordology i edited the response, just use the slash to pass the validation

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus There was a rather specific error given, and fixing the typo did not correct the error.  However, your edit still does not address the question, which specifically asks _why_ the backslash is disallowed.